# Creating Android Modular Applications on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, modularity

I am currently porting a framework for building applications on J2ME to Android. This framework consists of several projects that compile to libraries (jars). Each individual JAR can contain graphical data (resources, J4ME screens, etc.). Every project generally has a well defined entry point (module). When someone wants to build an application using the framework he must only create a Midlet project and add library dependencies and use the imported classes.

We have been using the same approach to develop the Android framework. In this case we have only used normal Java Projects inside Eclipse that compile to jar libraries. These projects have dependencies with the Android Framework (android.jar). When building a new application we create an Android Project inside Eclipse and add the dependencies.

Our next step is to build more advanced modules for Android that can also contain graphical information (Activities, Dialogs, Literals, Drawables, etc.). So far only an Android Eclipse project was needed (the end application), that contained all the graphical-related classes and resources. It seems that when using resources (literals, drawables, etc.) the only approach is to create an Android Application, since the resources are only referenceable by means of an integer handler automatically created by ADT plugin (R.XXX). So building graphical modules may not be built by means of plain Java jar projects.

Android developer information explains that modular applications are feasible, but I have not found a concise tutorial explaining the process, but some tips such as how to prevent an error to ocurr when an [application invokes an intent made available by other application](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/can-i-use-this-intent.html). This is valid when building applications that use resources from other applications. I do not need several installed applications on the system, but one built from several components.

Has anyone experience developing with similar requierements? Any good tutorial or tips to start out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the only available way is described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#librarySetup) as hinted by [the accepted answer of this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608680/is-is-possible-at-build-time-to-merge-android-applications).

The solution however is rather new (it only works with latest Android SDK tooks R6 and SDKs 2.0.X are left out of support). It has some major caveats on which I hope Google is already working:

- **No binary library linking**. This means that the main application needs access to sources (in Eclipse implies having all the linked library projects open).
- **The names of resources (layouts, drawables, etc) are treated globally**. This means that if you have two "main.xml" layouts, only the most relevant (uppermost in library list) will be used.
- **Missing funcionalities/BUGs**. The documentation states that exported activities of a library project must only be declared in AndroidManifest.xml of library project. This *does not work* in current version. Comments inside [TicTacToe](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/TicTacToeLib/index.html) example hints that this is the desired working, but for current release of Android Tools used activities from library projects must be explicitly defined in AndroidManifest.xml of main application project.